# Hypothesis testing using R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

> ```
>                                Republican(R)    Democrat(D)      Independent(I)
> Answer
> Should                          264(R)              299(D)                 351(I)
> Should not                       38(R)               55(D)                  77(I)
> Don't know/No answer             16(R)               15(D)                  22(I)
> Total                           318(R)               369(D)                450(I)
> ```

How do I use R to conduct an appropriate hypothesis test evaluating whether there is a difference in the proportion of Republicans and Democrats who think the full-body scans should be applied in airports? The cutoff value is $0.05$.

Comment: If you don't know what statistical method to use, that's a question for [stats.se]; if you do know what method you want to use but don't know how to do it in R, then you can ask it here. If you do know what method you want, be specific in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the $\chi^2$ test for independence and homogeneity in tables. For more information on this test you might want to look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_test#Chi-square_test_for_independence_and_homogeneity_in_tables).

In R you can conduct the test as follows:

```
# Chi-square test
chisq.test(matrix)

# Cramer's V as effect size
cv.test(matrix)
```

Whereby cv.test() is a custom function:

```
cv.test <- function(x) {
   CV <- sqrt(chisq.test(x)$statistic /
              (sum(x) * (min(dim(x)) - 1)))
   cat("Cramér V / Phi:\n")
   return(as.numeric(CV))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two questions for you:

1) Are you only interested in (A) Republican vs. Democrats, or interested in (B) whether political affiliation affects the Answers?

2) Are you interested in (A) {"should"} vs. {"should not" or "don't know"}, or interested in (B) comparing all three at once?

The χ2 answer provided by phx is illustrated on the most general case, ie. setting up the hypothesis with both (B)'s in the above questions. Any other desired hypothesis you wish to test can be still be tested using the χ2.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, I would have left a comment instead of posting an answer if I had the 50 reps. Will refrain from using answers as additional points of consideration subsequently